# merge two files of different length based on common column in linux

Tags: linux

I would like to merge two files (file 1 & file 2) based on a common column to give (file 3).
File 3 should have only the matched ids (mid) leaving out the mid=20
THE COMMON COLUMN HERE WOULD BE 'MID' AND THE MATCH IS BASED ON THAT COLUMN

I can do it with J command but the file 1 and file 2 are of different lenghts. Please suggest some ideas. Thanks in advance.

file 1

```
mid A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
18  we  gf  32  23  45  89
19  ew  fg  33  24  46  90
21  ew  fg  35  26  48  92
```

file 2

```
mid B1  B2  B3  B4
18  r40 1   103 NA
19  r41 1   104 NA
20  r42 1   105 NA
21  r43 1   106 NA
```

file 3

```
mid B1  B2  B3  B4  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
18  r40 1   103 NA  we  gf  32  23  45  89
19  r41 1   104 NA  ew  fg  33  24  46  90
21  r43 1   106 NA  ew  fg  35  26  48  92
```

Answer (score 0):

`join` was designed exactly for this kind of tasks:

```
join file2 file1
```

Comment: the original file is bit more complex and of different length, will that affect the output

Comment: it says that both the files is not sorted in order

Comment: @IPhoenix: So, sort them. `join <(sort file2) <(sort file1)`.

Comment: thanks but how to keep the header intact.. as it is also sorted out

Comment: @IPhoenix: `head`, `tail`?

Comment: used this code: awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1) in a{print $0, a[$1]}' file1.txt file2.txt                                                             but the output prints additional column ,,, where am i going wrong